# Proper way to pass optional values outside of functions in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, option-type

I'm using Alamofire & SwiftyJSON to fetch stock prices like so:

```
func stockFetcher() {

Alamofire.request(stockUrl).responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
    if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
        let json = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
        if let microsoftStockPrice = json["query"]["results"]["quote"][0]["Ask"].string {
            print(microsoftStockPrice)
            microsoftPrice = microsoftStockPrice
        }
    }
}
```

I initialized microsoftPrice as an optional string

```
var microsoftPrice: String?
```

Now if I try to use the value outside the function, say something like

```
print(microsoftPrice!)
```

In viewDidLoad, I get "unexpectedly found nil" error. Is there an extra step to unwrapping the value?

Comment: Most likely you are using the value before it has been fetched

Comment: when you print `microsoftStockPrice` inside the optional binding if statement, is the value `nil`?

Comment: Typo? `appleStockPrice` vs. `microsoftStockPrice`.

Comment: No, if I print within the stockFetcher() function the value pops up perfectly.

Comment: @rmaddy, was a typo, thanks for pointing it out. Question remains though!

Comment: Consider that `Alamofire.request` works asynchonously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use this function as a fetcher for the stock price, you need to add a completion handler as a parameter of the `stockFetcher()` function. You can do that like this...

```
func stockFetcher(completion: (String?) -> Void) { 
    Alamofire.request(stockUrl).responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
        if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
            let json = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
            if let microsoftStockPrice = json["query"]["results"]["quote"][0]["Ask"].string {
                completion(microsoftStockPrice)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using the completion handler will eliminate the need to have a `microsoftStockPrice` variable outside of the function. When Alamofire completes the request, that completion handler will be called with the stock price value. You can then use it like so...

```
stockFetcher(completion: {
    (stockPrice) -> Void in 
    // stockPrice will be available here
})
```

This is the syntax for Swift 3.

Comment: That does make sense and your code would prevent a crash, but it doesn't change the fact that microsoftPrice is nil - I'm wondering how I can get the value from my stockFetcher() function, and use it around my app. I thought I was doing that by getting microsoftStockPrice in my function and setting it to my microsoftPrice variable, then unwrapping it with ! when I want to use it.

Comment: Just saw your edit - I do think this is the problem, how do I ensure that the Alamofire request is finished before continuing with the execution of the app?

Comment: @d0xi45 Do the things you want to do **inside** the completion handler.

Comment: @justColbs Awesome, I'm new and haven't had to use completion handlers yet, so this is a great introduction! Thanks for your help.

Comment: @d0xi45 Happy to help! Completion handlers are very popular in advanced applications. It's a good practice to begin using!

Comment: @justColbs if I have several more companies in the stockFetcher() function set up just like microsoft, how do I specify which value I want? With the completion handler, stockPrice prints all of the stockPrices - what if I just want to print microsoftPrice, or just want to print applePrice, etc

Comment: @d0xi45 Do you mean specify a value to retrieve from the function rather than microsoftStockPrice ? If so, create another question if you don't mind. I think it is big enough to separate.

Comment: @justColbs Yeah, I'm trying to get the values individually so I can assign them to my company class - I'll make a new question hang on! Thanks for helping so far..

Comment: @justColbs here you go! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41110806/specifying-individual-values-from-a-completion-handler