# Specifying individual values from a completion handler

Tags: ios, swift

I'm learning about completion handlers currently and I'm trying to understand how to get values from outside the function to be used elsewhere in the app. This is my class:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON



var companyController: CompanyController?

let stockUrl = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20symbol%2C%20Ask%2C%20YearHigh%2C%20YearLow%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22AAPL%22%2C%22GOOG%22%2C%22TWTR%22%2C%22TSLA%22%2C%20%22SSNLF%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys"

let companies = companyList()





class Company: NSObject {

var companyName: String
var companyLogo: String
var stockPrice: String
init(companyName:String, companyLogo:String, stockPrice:String) {
    self.companyName = companyName
    self.companyLogo = companyLogo
    self.stockPrice = stockPrice
}
}


func stockFetcher(completion: @escaping (String?) -> Void) {

Alamofire.request(stockUrl).responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
    if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
        let json = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
        if let appleStockPrice = json["query"]["results"]["quote"][0]["Ask"].string {
            completion(appleStockPrice)
        }
        if let googleStockPrice = json["query"]["results"]["quote"][1]["Ask"].string {
            completion(googleStockPrice)
        }
        if let twitterStockPrice = json["query"]["results"]["quote"][2]["Ask"].string {
            completion(twitterStockPrice)
        }
        if let teslaStockPrice = json["query"]["results"]["quote"][3]["Ask"].string {
            completion(teslaStockPrice)
        }
        if let samsungStockPrice = json["query"]["results"]["quote"][4]["Ask"].string {
            completion(samsungStockPrice)
        }
        if let microsoftStockPrice = json["query"]["results"]["quote"][5]["Ask"].string {
            completion(microsoftStockPrice)
        }
        print(json)
    }
}
}





func companyList() -> [Company] {
let apple = Company(companyName: "Apple", companyLogo: "AppleLogo", stockPrice: appleStockPrice!)
let google = Company(companyName: "Google", companyLogo: "GoogleLogo", stockPrice: googleStockPrice!)
let twitter = Company(companyName: "Twitter", companyLogo: "TwitterLogo", stockPrice: twitterStockPrice!)
let tesla = Company(companyName: "Tesla", companyLogo: "TeslaLogo", stockPrice: teslaStockPrice!)
let samsung = Company(companyName: "Samsung", companyLogo: "SamsungLogo", stockPrice: samsungStockPrice!)
let microsoft = Company(companyName: "Microsoft", companyLogo: "MicrosoftLogo", stockPrice: microsoftStockPrice!)

return [apple, google, twitter, tesla, samsung, microsoft]
}
```

I'm trying to assign individual stock prices to their corresponding company in companyList so I can use those values later with something like

```
cell.textLabel?.text = companies[0].stockPrice
```

for apple's stock price, etc

```
    stockFetcher(completion: {
        (stockPrices) -> Void in
        print(stockPrices!)
    })
```

^ prints all the stockPrices. Do I need to call a separate completion handler for each company? Or is there an easier way?

Comment: Can you use the API to get the price for an individual stock? Or do you have to get them all at once? I would highly recommend making a request per stock price you need. Unless, you need  group of them at once.

Comment: I do need all of them at once, I need my table view in companyController to display the stock prices for each company upon loading.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all of the stock prices at once, have your completion handler return an array of the prices for each company. You can then initialize your Company object with the retrieved price.

**Ideally**, an API would return the name of the company with the price and any other data. You could take the data (likely in JSON format) from the API and then use a for loop to get all of the Company objects out of it. However, it does not seem like the api does this? Correct me if i'm wrong.

Here is how you would modify your function to return an array...

```
func stockFetcher(completion: @escaping ([String]?) -> Void) {
    Alamofire.request(stockUrl).responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
        var prices = [String]()
        if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
            let json = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
            if let microsoftStockPrice = json["query"]["results"]["quote"][5]["Ask"].string {
                 prices.append(microsoftStockPrice)
            }
            if let appleStockPrice = json["query"]["results"]["quote"]["6"]["Ask"].string {
                 prices.append(appleStockPrice)
            }
            completion(prices)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not that I know of - Alamofire returns JSON with the company name, high price, low price, and ask. As far as I know there is no way to loop through the values, but I'm pretty new so there could be a way. As for having my completion handler return an array, how do I specify that?

Comment: @d0xi45 I hav edited my answer to answer that question. If you want to have the function return the name of the company AND the price of the stock, you should take a look at Tuples in the Apple docs and return an array of Tuples. Again, the ideal way would be to iterate through the JSON and create a Company object for each item, but i'm not sure what the JSON looks like enough to answer that.

Answer (score 0):

Why don yout try something like this?

```
func stockFetcher(completion: @escaping (data [String]) -> Void) {

Alamofire.request(stockUrl).responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in

if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {

    var stocks: [String] = []
    for stockJson in JSON(responseData.result.value!).array {
        stock.append(//get your data for every stock)
    }
    completion(microsoftStockPrice)
    } 
}
```

This way completion block will be called just once an have array of stock or some else data you need. Is this what you are trying to do?